# despite sourcing workspace, 'roscore' command not found

Tags: linux, ros-kinetic, jetson, source, setup.bash

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I used to open terminal and be able to do ros commands such as roscore, rostopic, rosrun, roslaunch and catkin_make.

But now, something become broken, and I need to do `source ~/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash` **everytime when I open terminal**. I dont know why.

I have checked .bashrc file. `source /opt/ros/kinetic/setup.bash`  and `source ~/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash` is there.
Can you help me?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/337410/despite-sourcing-workspace,-%27roscore%27-command-not-found/) by [june2473](https://answers.ros.org/users/44408/june2473/) on ROS Answers with karma: 83 on 2019-11-12

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Delb](https://answers.ros.org/users/33811/delb/) on 2019-11-12**:
Can you open a terminal and execute the command `env | grep ROS` and show us the ouput ?

**Comment by [june2473](https://answers.ros.org/users/44408/june2473/) on 2019-11-12**:
output:

```
ROS_ROOT=/opt/ros/kinetic/share/ros
ROS_PACKAGE_PATH=/home/nvidia/catkin_ws/src:/opt/ros/kinetic/share
ROS_MASTER_URI=http://10.42.0.243:11311
ROS_VERSION=1
ROS_HOSTNAME=JETSON_HOSTNAME
ROSLISP_PACKAGE_DIRECTORIES=/home/nvidia/catkin_ws/devel/share/common-lisp
ROS_DISTRO=kinetic
ROS_IP=10.42.0.243
ROS_ETC_DIR=/opt/ros/kinetic/etc/ros
```

**Comment by [Delb](https://answers.ros.org/users/33811/delb/) on 2019-11-12**:
The environment variables look fine to me, but you can't run `roscore` ?

**Comment by [june2473](https://answers.ros.org/users/44408/june2473/) on 2019-11-12**:
I can't. command not found

**Comment by [june2473](https://answers.ros.org/users/44408/june2473/) on 2019-11-12**:
auto-completion suggests me:
https://yadi.sk/i/tzHElwIZVytlXg

**Comment by [Delb](https://answers.ros.org/users/33811/delb/) on 2019-11-12**:
Indeed that's strange that your autocompletion have `roscd`, `rosdep` etc but not `roscore`. Have ou reinstalled ros recently ?

Moreover what is the ouput of `which roscore` when you open a new terminal ? Same question after you run `source opt/ros/kinetic/setup.bash` ?

**Comment by [june2473](https://answers.ros.org/users/44408/june2473/) on 2019-11-12**:
when I open new terminal `which roscore` gives nothing

then I do `source opt/ros/kinetic/setup.bash` and `which roscore` gives me:

```
/opt/ros/kinetic/bin/roscore
```

and roscore gives me:
https://yadi.sk/i/CwNGeQGlHNphdQ

**Comment by [june2473](https://answers.ros.org/users/44408/june2473/) on 2019-11-12**:
I haven't reinstalled ros.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

my .bashrc was containing some crap. that was the problem. nothing interesting. problem solved.

---

Originally posted by [june2473](https://answers.ros.org/users/44408/june2473/) with karma: 83 on 2019-11-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0